# accepts_nested_attributes_for causing infinite loop in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models that both accept_nested_attributes_for each other. I know this is causing issues with rails_admin but can't seem to figure out the appropriate command to exclude nested attributes in my configuration. Ideally I would like to exclude nested attributes for all models so that this problem does not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Branden,

You need to inform the bi-direction association using `inverse_of`:

Ex:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, :inverse_of => :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

For both sides of association:

```ruby
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

More information in the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations

Answer (score 0):

I removed relation from RailsAdmin sight

```
class MyModelWithProblem
  include RailsAdmin::MyModelWithProblem

  with_options class_name: :MyModelWithProblem do
    belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :groups, optional: true
    has_many :groups, inverse_of: :parent, foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
  end

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :groups, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end



module RailsAdmin
  module MyModelWithProblem
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      rails_admin do
        exclude_fields :groups
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I think, this is only temporary solution